# Комбинация клавиш

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! У меня вот такая проблема:

Есть код:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
if ((e.altKey && String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/\d/))){alert(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))}
});
```

Мне нужно, что бы при отпускании комбинации Alt+цифры, оно показывало какие цифры я нажал вместе с alt. Вот так '43147'.


Надеюсь поняли)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну например [так можно](https://jsfiddle.net/Uwi74/8buy3g4c/):

```
var gKeyStore = [];

// ловим нажатия цифр с зажатым Alt
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.altKey && String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/\d/)) {
        gKeyStore.push(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
    }
});

// ловим отжатие Alt
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (!e.altKey) {
        if(gKeyStore.length > 0) { 
            // замените на alert при необходимости
            console.log(gKeyStore.join('')); 
            gKeyStore = [];
        }
    }
});
```